# Can't retrieve value from Bundle android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, bundle, getstring

Inside my fragment in the onCreateView method, I retrieve the Bundle which was set for the fragment using the following code:

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
String value = args.getString("fixedExpenseId");
```

But somehow the value is null when I run my code.

When I debug my program I retrieve the following variables:

[image: Image of debug results]

As you kan see, the key I used is the same as the one inside the Bundle.

How is it possible that I retrieve null inside my

> value

variable?

Comment: show code where you are setting Bundle using `setArguments`

Comment: Are you using DialogFragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking at the screenshot, it looks like you switched the key and value variables. You set the key "2" to "fixedExpenseId", and not the key "fixedExpenseId" to "2".

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Just check that you are putting right value in bundle with right key i.e. in your case `fixedExpenseId`.